# Graph a piecewise function with a jump

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to graph a piecewise function using one `\addplots` line? Here is a MWE that demonstrates what I want to do:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
    g(\x)=\x<0 ? x+2 : 0.5*x-2;}]
    \begin{axis}[
      grid=both, 
      grid style={line width=0.35pt, draw=gray!75},
      axis lines=center,
      axis line style={-},
      xmin=-5, xmax=5,
      ymin=-5, ymax=5,
      ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0.5pt,fill=white,opacity=1.0, text opacity=1},
      every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.95pt, color=red, samples=500},
      ]
        \addplot[domain=-5:0] {g(x)};
        \addplot[domain= 0:5] {g(x)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use `\addplot[domain=-5:5] {g(x)};` with some kind of modification so that there isn't a line between the end of the first half and beginning of the second half.

**EDIT:** 
Below is the code that I'm actually tinkering with. I took the suggestion for `samples at` and defined the function to be `inf` anywhere where there was a jump discontinuity:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={only marks,mark=*, line width=0.2pt, mark size=1.5pt}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={fill=white,only marks,mark=*, line width=1.0pt, mark size=1.5pt}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
    g(\x)=\x<-2 ? 1/(2*(\x+2))+3 : 
      (\x==-2 ? inf :
      (\x< -1 ? 1/(\x+2)-2:
      (\x==-1 ? inf : 
      (\x<  1 ? -\x^2+1: 
      (\x<  3 ? 2*(\x-2)^2-2: -0.5*exp(-\x+3.7)+1))));}]
    \begin{axis}[
      grid=both, 
      grid style={line width=0.35pt, draw=gray!75},
      axis lines=center,
      axis line style={black,-},
      xmin=-5, xmax=5,
      ymin=-5, ymax=5,
      xtick={-6,-5,...,6},
      ytick={-6,-5,...,6},
      ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0.5pt,fill=white,opacity=1.0, text opacity=1},
      every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.95pt, color=red},
      ]
        %% Using 'samples at' instead of domain to control plotting discontinuities
        \addplot[samples at={-5,-4.95,...,-2.005,-2,-1.95,...,-1.05,-1.005,-1,-0.95,...,5}, unbounded coords=jump] {g(x)};
        \addplot[holdot] coordinates{(-1,0)(2,-2)};
        \addplot[soldot] coordinates{(-1,-1)(2,-1)};
        \draw[dashed, red, line width=0.95pt] ({axis cs:-2,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:-2,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1});
        \addplot[dashed, samples at={-5,-3}]{3};
        \addplot[dashed, samples at={3,5}]{1};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following graph:
[image: piecewise graph with 2 jump discontinuities]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unbounded coords=jump`. To this end, lets introduce an unbounded coordinate at 0,

```
g(\x)=\x<0 ? x+2 : (\x>0 ? 0.5*x-2 : inf)
```

Assuming you do not want to use an unnecessarily large number of samples, you might want to use

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
    g(\x)=\x<0 ? x+2 : (\x>0 ? 0.5*x-2 : inf);}]
    \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump,
      grid=both, 
      grid style={line width=0.35pt, draw=gray!75},
      axis lines=center,
      axis line style={-},
      xmin=-5, xmax=5,
      ymin=-5, ymax=5,
      ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0.5pt,fill=white,opacity=1.0, text opacity=1},
      every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.95pt, color=red, samples=500},
      ]
        \addplot[samples at={-5,-0.01,0,0.01,5}] {g(x)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really insist on `domain=-5:5`, use

```
 \addplot[samples=501,domain=-5:5] {g(x)};
```

but this has a huge number of samples, yet it produces virtually the same result.

Comment: The ```samples at``` trick is not one I had thought of. The situation I'm thinking of is a piecewise function that isn't a linear function and has at least 2 different jumps. Is it possible to give the ```samples at``` key a range of values? I tried using ```inf``` and ```unbounded coords=jump``` in my original file, but it didn't seem to do what I wanted.

Comment: @pwesterbaan You can definitely use `samples at` with everything that works in `\foreach`, such as `samples at={-5,-4.9,....,-0.1,0,0.2,0.4,...,5}`. Very often `samples at` allows you to sample the function "better" (if you know how the function looks like, of course).

Comment: @pwesterbaan There are attempts to change the `foreach` parser, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494722/194703.

Comment: There is also `samples at={-5, -0.001,0,5}`