# Confirmation on input types supported by \keeppages?

Tags: compiling, page

It seems a little odd that `\keeppages{x-y}` is not supported?  Perhaps I'm not using the proper syntax.

This code should be adapted to satisfy the case that the first several pages of the document are labelled as i, ii, iii, iv, etc.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\discardpages}[1]{% \discardpages{<csv list>}
  \xdef\discard@pages{#1}% Store pages to discard
  \AtBeginShipout{% At shipout, decide whether to discard page/not
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to handle each page entry in csv list
      \ifnum\value{page}=##1\relax%
        \AtBeginShipoutDiscard% Discard page/not
        \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
      \fi%
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\discard@pages}% Process list of pages to discard
  }%
}
\newif\ifkeeppage
\newcommand{\keeppages}[1]{% \keeppages{<csv list>}
  \xdef\keep@pages{#1}% Store pages to keep
  \AtBeginShipout{% At shipout, decide whether to discard page/not
    \keeppagefalse%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% How to handle each page entry in csv list
      \ifnum\value{page}=##1\relax%
        \keeppagetrue% Page should be kept
        \gdef\do####1{}% Do nothing further
      \fi%
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\keep@pages}% Process list of pages to keep
    \ifkeeppage\else\AtBeginShipoutDiscard\fi% Discard page/not
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Are you talking about the maco defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection)? It simply was not programmed to take page ranges.

Comment: I'd add that there are limitations to the approach described in the macros that @WillieWong linked to that limit their usability. What's more, you end up having to process all the pages regardless of whether you want to keep them so you're not saving much time there.

In the olden days, we would do page subsetting in the DVI driver and that's still a possibility—running straight LaTeX and then dvipdf. Otherwise, you might want to look at the myriad tools or subsetting pages from a PDF file that are available such as https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/extract-pages-from-pdf.html

Comment: @WillieWong, Yes.  What is involved in supporting range input? `\keeppages` seems to be an ideal solution.  A `pdfpages` based approach does not work so well with rotated landscape pages from `pdflscape`.

Comment: you can search around this website to see. For example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494712/smart-expansion-of-a-range-to-a-list-of-numbers

Comment: But as @DonHosek mentioned: to even know which page is which requires processing the entire document, unless you manually intervene using `\include`s and `\includeonly`s. So rather than using a LaTeX solution, personally I would just use [one of the many tools for manipulating PDFs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PDF,_PS_and_DjVu#Extract_page_range_from_PDF,_split_multipage_PDF_document) (probably qpdf is the easiest to use if you need to mix specific pages and page ranges) to process the file after compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking "why" is rather senseless. The command has been written as it has been written.

If you want to select by page range you could use the `pagesel` package.

Activate the page selecting option only after the document has been fully compiled and all cross references resolved. The page range uses *absolute* page numbers.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[4-7,9] %activate options after a full compilation cycle
 {pagesel}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
TITLE
\mainmatter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn {15}{\newpage A~PAGE}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is also selectp.sty. I should check that it still works! And also check if it conflicts with everyshi.sty.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau the pagesel docu mentions selectp "for plain and latex 2.09". Regarding everyshi: with the upcoming latex it will/should no longer be used (similar atbegshi). The relevant hooks will then be in the kernel, and we replace the styles with small wrappers for the user commands. So you should test if the package conflicts with latex-dev.

Comment: Hi @Ulrike, I don't recall anything in selectp that wouldn't work in later LaTeX. I just did a quick check. It works; but (a) the documentation talks about \documentstyle, and (b) one can't specify the page range(s) as an optional argument. I could patch it, but there's probably no need, given pagesel, which has more forms of page selection. Hmmm. I don't see the important ability to select pages when there are overlapping sequences (frontmatter and mainmatter). Does pagesel handle it?

Comment: pagesel uses an absolute page counter, so there are no overlapping page numbers. Did you check with the newest latex-dev? I can't test now, but as does change shipout, there could be a conflict.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive comments on question title and thanks for your `pagesel` solution.